# How to add a variable to express-mailer

Tags: javascript, express

I'm using [express-mailer](https://github.com/RGBboy/express-mailer) to send emails, but the documented way to add a variable to an email template is not working. Does anyone know the solution?

```
  app.mailer.send('email', {
    to: 'example@example.com', // REQUIRED. This can be a comma delimited string just like a normal email to field. 
    subject: 'Test Email', // REQUIRED.
    otherProperty: 'Other Property' // All additional properties are also passed to the template as local variables.
  }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // handle error
      console.log(err);
      res.send('There was an error sending the email');
      return;
    }
    res.send('Email Sent');
  });

  //- in jade template
  h1 {{otherProprety}}
```

Does not work.